# Apply an entry-dependent function to each entry of a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: function, matlab, matrix

I have a square matrix `A` and I would like to apply a *different* function to each entry of `A`. In other words, I want to obtain as output a new matrix `B` where `B(i,j)= fun(A(i,j))`, and this for all the `i,j`.

For simplicity, assume that I want to use the function `sin()` for each entry, but where the phase depends on the specific entry `i,j`. How can I do this? I would like to avoid a for loop for all the entry, i.e.

```
for i=1:N
    for j=1:N
        B(i,j)= A(i,j).* fun(i,j)
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you explain precisely what you want and why you can't make it work, provide a minimal example.

Comment: I provided an example

Comment: But what is  `T`  ?

Comment: A scalar number

Comment: Using broadcasting, you can for example obtain the same result with: `sin(2*pi*[1:N].'.*[1:N]/T)`

Comment: I expanded the code. I was missing the dependency on the entries of the matrix A. The function fun is a generic function, which is parametric on the position of the entry. For instance it could be exp(-(i*j))

Comment: The same logic using broadcasting could still be applied with `exp(-(i*j))`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It suffices to solve the problem. By any chance, do you know whether this could be extended to user-defined functions? For instance applying an anonymous function instead of a built-in Matlab one?

Comment: Some function can be vectorized, some other can not, it's a case-by-case type of problem.

Comment: For user-defined functions, you could define a cell array of functions and set each function `f{1,1} = @(x)(somef(x)); f{1,2} = @(x)...` then use the functions as `f{i,j}(A(i,j))`